# SVD - why do we complete matrices $U$ and $V$ with the vectors that form a basis for the nullspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

[SVD picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AefI4.png)

Normally, in theoretical demonstrations, $U$ has size $(m, n)$ instead of $(m, r)$. Why is that so? Is there a reason why we include a basis for the nullspace as well in the matrices $U$ and $V$?

Comment: It is convenient to have a decomposition in which the sizes of $U,\Sigma,V$ depend only on the size of the matrix $A = U \Sigma V^T$ and not on the particular choice of $A$ (i.e. on its rank). This way, theoretical computations can be done without having to account for different possible matrix sizes.

Comment: "Worse" still, it is common to take $m$ to be a matrix with size $m \times m$, so that the columns of $U$ and $V$ are extended to include a full basis of the left and right nullspaces of $A$ (respectively). It is often convenient to have $U,V$ be square orthogonal matrices.